# LibGDX - How do I correctly add ExtendViewports?

Tags: libgdx, viewport

I'm new to LibGDX and I am trying to get my screen resolution sizes set up first before I get into the actual game itself. Before I added extendViewport I had an orthographic Camera and an Image that displayed. But when I got rid of the orthographic camera and added the Viewport the image disappeared. Here is the code i have for the the screen.

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
   SlingshotSteve game; 

   private ExtendViewport viewport;
   PerspectiveCamera camera;

   public void Menu(SlingshotSteve game){
       this.game = game;
   }


   SpriteBatch batch;
   TextureRegion backgroundTexture;
   Texture texture;

   GameScreen(final SlingshotSteve gam) {
        this.game = gam; 


    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.jpg"));
    backgroundTexture = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 500, 500);

    Music mp3Sound = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("rain.mp3"));
    mp3Sound.setLooping(true);
    mp3Sound.play();

}

public void render(float delta) {   
      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      camera.update();
      batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

      batch.begin();
      batch.draw(backgroundTexture, 0, 0, SlingshotSteve.WIDTH, SlingshotSteve.HEIGHT); 
      batch.end();

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height); 

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
       batch.dispose();
       texture.dispose();

}


@Override
public void show() {
    camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
    viewport = new ExtendViewport(800, 480, camera);

}
}
```

The other question I have is that this screen is the main game screen where Level 1 is going to occur. Since I added a main menu I had to switch from the "Application Listener" to the "Implement Screen". Is this correct, or do I have to go back to the Application Listener to get the Create() method? I'm not completely sure what everything means so If someone could please explain this to me that would be great!